# Magento 2.3.5 This identifier is reserved for "CMS No Cookies Page"

Tags: cms, cms-pages, magento2.3.5

I have 4 stores: Each store have the same `enable-cookies` I would like that each cookie cms url key have a different url so that is relevant to that store E.G:

French store URL Key: `activer-les-cookies` as all it's contents are in french so it make sense to have the url in french too.

I' know the exception is coming from here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/Page.php

But I'm looking to find a way to update the url as this wouldn't let me to it via the admin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this at database level:

```sql
update cms_page set identifier='activer-les-cookies' where page_id = <page_id>;
```

Just make sure you update the <page_id> with your real page ID.

Comment: can you please help me here mam? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333053/77631

Comment: @Diana Botean I have thought of that already but my concern is to understand the impact also this could have if is changed ?

Comment: I checked this on a test environment and didn't see any negative behavior, so i suggest you do the same, check this on a test machine and see if anything pops up.